# Download the streaming video in server

Tags: pi-4, video, streaming-video, picamera, libcamera

In order to stream video over the LAN, I used a Raspberry Pi Zero W. I used this MJPEG server code to stream the video over the LAN.
[mpjpeg streaming program] [1](https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2/blob/main/examples/mjpeg_server.py)
Currently, I want to download and save the video to a local server.